# int of numbers to time in php

Tags: php, datetime

I have the following Digits of Integers...

```
$int = 20130923122843977;

// This year   yyyy - 2013
// This Month    mm - 09
// This Date     dd - 23
// This Hour     hh - 12
// Minutes       mn - 28
// This Seconds  se - 43
// Millisecond   ms - 43
```

I have tried to get it using substr.

```
$yy = substr($time, 0, 4);  //return year (YYYY) -
```

but It is confusing some how when i come to seconds and milliseconds, because i should insert it to mysql database, how do i achieve that.
some help?

Comment: How do you get such a weirdly formatted string in the first place?

Comment: You should use mm/dd/yyyy h:i:s format in php and store the string in your db having a column set to date/time

Comment: ohhh, first why negative? secondly the file name is different one another by millisecond so the file name must go deep to this time format.

Comment: mm/dd/yyyy, is just date stamp...what i want is more than that...

Comment: @MR.Alien, give me some example using the above name...

Comment: @MR.Test http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/datetime.html

Comment: `$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('YmdHisu`); $dateForDB = $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s u');`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, If you just have this kind of format time string:

```
<?php
$int = 20130923122843977;
$Y = substr($int, 0, 4);
$m = substr($int, 4, 2);
$d = substr($int, 6, 2);
$H = substr($int, 8, 2);
$i = substr($int, 10, 2);
$s = substr($int, 12, 2);

$ms = substr($int, 14);
$time = mktime($H, $i, $s, $m, $d, $Y); 

echo date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $time);    //2013-09-23 12:28:43
```

#### the result of the code: http://codepad.org/pmbIJdkT

Comment: you are near to what i need, but if you test it..On $m instead of getting 09 i see 28 why? please help...

Comment: this is what i get according to your code... 2013-28-23-12 28 43, why 28.

Comment: Are you using $m for both months and minutes? Minutes should be $i

Comment: if you echo $mm you will see what would be the out put, I don't understand either...

Comment: `$m` is month, `$i` is minute. see the result of the code here: http://codepad.org/y6oJOlJR

Comment: Sorry, but no `$mm` in my answer, check your code.

Comment: This is the latest code, http://codepad.org/pmbIJdkT, I missed `$H` in my answer, I updated the answer.

Comment: yes, that really looks correct, why i get then some strange number when i run on my server, is there some time setting i should do..might be...

Comment: i think i have problem with setting time zone might be?

Comment: Would you paste your code in you question, let me have a look.

Comment: You get it i just set the time Zone to my City, Now it is working like charm...Thanks @srain...Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the function you need, your $int was all messed up, but my function can still overcome that and you can still input ints or strings =]

Milliseconds goes unused, but still there for your reference

```
$int = 2013092312284343;


function weird_date_to_timestamp ($time)
{
    // convert to string (if you cast you get exponential notation)
    $time = number_format($time, 0,'','');
    $time = str_split($time, 2);

    $a['year'] = $time[0] . $time[1];
    $a['month'] = $time[2];
    $a['day'] = $time[3];
    $a['hour'] = $time[4];
    $a['min'] = $time[5];
    $a['sec'] = $time[6];
    $a['msec'] = $time[7];

    date_default_timezone_set('UTC');
    return strtotime("{$a['year']}-{$a['month']}-{$a['day']} {$a['hour']}:{$a['min']}:{$a['sec']}"); 
}

$t_stamp = weird_date_to_timestamp($int);

// you can give this out as input to mysql
print date("Y-m-d H:i:s", $t_stamp);
```

Comment: That is also correct answer, Thanks @Ibarra

Answer (score 1):

## PHP

Use [`DateTime::createFromFormat`](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php) method:

```
$int = '20130923122843977';
$dt = DateTime::createFromFormat('YmdHisu', $int);
echo $dt->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
# 2013-09-23 12:28:43
```

[Demo](https://eval.in/54169).

## MySQL

You can use [`STR_TO_DATE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date) function to convert to datetime format:

```
SELECT STR_TO_DATE('20130923122843977', '%Y%m%d%H%i%s%x');
# 2013-09-23 12:28:43
```

Comment: That is really Nice and tricky one.

Comment: but what about the Millisecond issues, how do i do it in mysql

Comment: MySQL cannot store miliseconds in any date-time field type, and no date-time functions work with them. If you don't need them, ignore them.

Comment: i really need them, the file name is differ one to another by Millisecond, How do i achieve that?

Comment: Save them in extra field.

Comment: I mean can i do like this, First Insert the above $dt like timestamp and the 3 digit Millisecond in another column, and order by first time-stamp then millisecond column, does it work the logic?

Comment: Yes, you can do it like that. Use `$dt->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');` for DATETIME type field, and `$dt->format('u');` for INT type field.